# R. Compare magnitud of response over time among many individuals

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I have 1000 individuals with measurements of plasmatic HDL levels over the last 15 years. The number of measurements per individual ranges from 1 to 15, and were not taken in the same dates. I would like to compare the HDL levels over time in the individuals and make a ranking of those individuals whose HDL levels are consistently the highest over time. There must be some sort of linear regression method for measuring this effect, but I am not acquainted with it. One concern is what is the minimum number of measurements per individual that I should consider in order to include/exclude certain individuals in the analysis.

I have a data.frame with 4 columns: Individual_ID, HDL_level, Age (at the time of measurement) and Sex. This is a data.frame with a toy example:

```
Individual_ID  HDL_level  Age (years old)  Sex
1              50         12.3             M
1              52.1       15.4             M
1              55.3       17.1             M
2              45         12.1             M
2              46.3       12.1             M
3              60         14.3             F
3              55         16.2             F
...            ...        ...              ...
```

I would like to do 2 rankings using R: 1) male and female considered together, NO adjustment for sex; and 2) male and female considered together, adjusting for sex.  In both of them, I would like to adjust for diet (e.g., whether or not they ingested food during the 3 last hours before the measurements were taken). Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question might be more suited to [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How many individuals are in your dataset, and how many measurements per individual do you have (for instance, between 3 and 8 measurements)? Seems like a case for a mixed model.

Comment: Thank you @DominicComtois. As I mentioned, I have 1000 individuals and 1-15 measurements per individual.

Comment: Np! Sorry I hadn't read the first paragraph carefully... I think you can delete this post now if you posted on Cross-Validated.